# Morphisms which are "finite" or "finite type"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes and $f:X\to Y$ a morphism between them.

We say that $f$ is of **finite type** if for every affine open $spec(A)=U\subset Y$ there exists a finite affine (open) cover of $f^{-1}(U)$ by $\{ V_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $V_i=spec(B_i)$, such that $B_i$ is a finitely generated $A$-algbera.

On the other hand $f$ is  **finite** if $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine, say $f^{-1}(U)=spec(B)$, and $A$ is finite $B$-module.

I was wondering why don't we have the intermediate notion as following.

The map $f$ is such that for every affine $U=spec(A)$ we have $f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$ where $V_i=spec(B_i)$ and $B_i$ is finite $A$-module. 
Let's call the this property ***quasi finite type***.

So the question is as follows:
Suppose $f$ a morphism of schemes was of ***quasi finite type*** then would it imply that it is actually **finite**.

If yes, then there is no need of such a definition.

If no, is it just because we don't see this kind of property in "nature" and hence don't need to define it.

Comment: Note that a localization of a finite module is no longer finite, so even if $B$ is a finite $A$ module and $spec B=spec B_0\cup spec B_1$ we dont have that $B_i$ is a finite $A$ module.

Comment: Your definition of quasi finite type will actually imply that the map is finite, so you do not need such a convoluted definition.

Comment: @Mohan could you please explain more as to why the map is finite.

Comment: I will give you a starting point. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of irreducible varieties, where $Y$ is affine. Let $U\subset X$ be an open affine set with $f:U\to Y$ be finite. Then $U=X$. Remember that finite morphisms are proper.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of a *quasi-finite* morphism already exists: it is a morphism of finite type with finite fibers.

*Zariski's main theorem*, in its Grothendieck's version, asserts that a quasi-finite morphism decomposes as an open immersion into a finite scheme.

Comment: I think the notion of quasi-finite you mentioned is different from the definition  (of quasi finite type) in the question.

Comment: At the ring level, it is roughly a localisation $S_f$ of a finite  $R$-algebra $S$. Isn't it the same?

Comment: I can't see how the definition in the question of quasi finite type implies finite fibers.

Comment: Finite morphisms have finite fibers.

Comment: But it is not a finite morphism, is it.

Comment: Your definition stipulates a covering by affine open sets corresponding to finite algebras.

Comment: From wiki page of quasi finite morphism an equivalent version tells me that for a morphism of finite type to quasi finite it is enough to have finite extension of residue fields. This is implied by my definition. So the map is indeed quasi finite.